# How to properly check if a value is infinite or nan ic c++(msvc2010)

Tags: c++, templates, floating-point

I'm almost 100% positive that this has been asked before, but my search on this did'nt lead to a satisfying anwser.

So lets begin. All of my problems came from this little issue: -1.#IND000.
So basically my value was either nan or infinite, so the calcs blew up causing errors.

Since I'm working with floats, I've been using float.IsNan() and float.IsInfinity() in C#
But when I started coding in C++ I havent quite found equivalent functions in C++.
So I wrote a template for checking if the float is nan, like this:

```
template <typename T> bool isnan (T value)
{ return value != value; }
```

But how should I write a function to define if the float is infinite? And after all Is my nan check properly done? Also I'm doing the ckecks in a timed loop, so the template should act fast.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6):

Note that:

- `x` is NaN if and only if `x != x`.
- `x` is NaN or an infinity if and only if `x - x != 0`.
- `x` is a zero or an infinity if and only if `x + x == x`.
- `x` is a zero if and only if `x == 0`.
- If `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is `0` or `1`, then `x` is an infinity if and only if `x + DBL_MAX == x`.
- `x` is positive infinity if and only if `x + infinity == x`.

I do not think there is anything wrong with using comparisons like the above instead of standard library functions, even if those standard library functions exist.  In fact, after a discussion with David Heffernan in the comments, I would recommend using the arithmetic comparisons above over the `isinf`/`isfinite`/`isnan` macros/functions.

I see that you are using a Microsoft compiler here.  I do not have one installed.  What follows is all done with reference to the `gcc` on my Arch box, namely `gcc version 4.9.0 20140521 (prerelease) (GCC)`, so this is at most a portability note for you.  Try something similar with your compiler and see which variants, if any, tell the compiler what's going on and which just make it give up.

Consider the following code:

```
int foo(double x) {
  return x != x;
}

void tva(double x) {
  if (!foo(x)) {
    x += x;
    if (!foo(x)) {
      printf(":(");
    }
  }
}
```

Here `foo` is an implementation of `isnan`.  `x += x` will not result in a NaN unless `x` was NaN before.  Here is the code generated for `tva`:

```
0000000000000020 <_Z3tvad>:
  20:   66 0f 2e c0             ucomisd %xmm0,%xmm0
  24:   7a 1a                   jp     40 <_Z3tvad+0x20>
  26:   f2 0f 58 c0             addsd  %xmm0,%xmm0
  2a:   66 0f 2e c0             ucomisd %xmm0,%xmm0
  2e:   7a 10                   jp     40 <_Z3tvad+0x20>
  30:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
  35:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  37:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   3c <_Z3tvad+0x1c>
  3c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
  40:   f3 c3                   repz retq
```

Note that the branch containing the `printf` was not generated.  What happens if we replace `foo` with `isnan`?

```
00000000004005c0 <_Z3tvad>:
  4005c0:       66 0f 28 c8             movapd %xmm0,%xmm1
  4005c4:       48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp
  4005c8:       f2 0f 11 4c 24 08       movsd  %xmm1,0x8(%rsp)
  4005ce:       e8 4d fe ff ff          callq  400420 <__isnan@plt>
  4005d3:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  4005d5:       75 17                   jne    4005ee <_Z3tvad+0x2e>
  4005d7:       f2 0f 10 4c 24 08       movsd  0x8(%rsp),%xmm1
  4005dd:       66 0f 28 c1             movapd %xmm1,%xmm0
  4005e1:       f2 0f 58 c1             addsd  %xmm1,%xmm0
  4005e5:       e8 36 fe ff ff          callq  400420 <__isnan@plt>
  4005ea:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  4005ec:       74 0a                   je     4005f8 <_Z3tvad+0x38>
  4005ee:       48 83 c4 18             add    $0x18,%rsp
  4005f2:       c3                      retq
  4005f3:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  4005f8:       bf 94 06 40 00          mov    $0x400694,%edi
  4005fd:       48 83 c4 18             add    $0x18,%rsp
  400601:       e9 2a fe ff ff          jmpq   400430 <printf@plt>
  400606:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

It appears that `gcc` has no idea what `isnan` does!  It generates the dead branch with the `printf` and it generates two separate calls to `isnan`.

My point here is that using the `isnan` macro/function confounds gcc's value analysis.  It has no idea that `isnan(x)` if and only if `x` is NaN.  Having compiler optimisations work is often much more important than generating the fastest possible code for a given primitive.

Comment: Thanks, seems informative, will check this out.
Tho I dont understand why someone would downvote this anwser...

Comment: Why would you prefer these approaches to the standard library facilities? Unless they have an advantage, surely the standard library is to be preferred.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I didn't say I preferred it; I said there's nothing wrong with it.  It has the disadvantage of looking dead to people who aren't familiar with floating-point arithmetic, but the advantage of looking the same in every language.  This disadvantage is enough that I would usually use library facilities if I know where to find them and I trust them.

Comment: Another disadvantage is performance. On some hardware, with certain inputs some of these comparisons are slow.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Indeed, but that cuts both ways.  My copy of gcc, for instance, compiles `int foo(double x) { return x != x; }` into a `vucomisd/setp` pair.  Calling `isnan` instead results in an actual call to the C library's `isnan` function, which is implemented in the bit-hacky way.  It's notable that gcc has builtins for neither.  However, `isnan` confounds gcc's value analysis while `x != x` does not.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Consider the following function:  `void tva(double x) { if (!foo(x)) { x += x; if (!foo(x)) printf(":(\n"); } }`.  If `foo` is a NaN-check that checks `x != x`, gcc correctly recognises that the sadface branch is dead.  If `foo` calls `isnan` instead, gcc generates the dead sadface branch.  So yes, there's a performance issue; don't use `isnan` when `x != x` suffices in a piece of complicated code.

Comment: The perf issue is that checking with equality operators can be orders of magnitude slower than bit twiddling

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes.  However, if you use `isnan` instead, gcc at least will have no idea what you're doing.  The cost of foregoing optimisations could well be more significant than the immediate cost of the comparison.

Comment: What's the problem with calling functions?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Apart from a small list of builtins, most modern compilers do not speculate about the behaviour of functions whose code is only known at link time.

Comment: The performance of the equality operator on some hardware with some input (e.g. NaNs) is orders of magnitude worse than bit twiddling. Calling a function is trivial by comparison. I think it is very poor form to use these non-semantic expressions. Interesting to know I agree, but not for use in the real world.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Did you read anything I wrote?  The performance of bit twiddling is infinitely many orders of magnitude slower than having the compiler prove that the non-NaN case cannot exist on a particular branch, which is what gcc can do if you check `x != x` and can't if you check `isnan(x)`.

Comment: For different x, you expression can evaluate to either true or false

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: False.  `x + x` is never NaN unless `x` is NaN.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Then you didn't make it to that branch in the first place.  Do you know how to trace through code?

Comment: Apparently you are superior to me.

Comment: I see what you mean with your edit. Hard to read in comments. But it's an artificial example. But even if the compiler can kill the dead code, isnan will still be so much faster on the first check that it still wins. On certain hardware. Eg x87.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Of course it's artificial.  The idea is to get the point across as simply as possible.  The compiler has a better idea of what `x` is within the `!foo(x)` branch but not the `!isnan(x)` branch.  This happens whether or not the content of the branch is trivial.  (I'd be interested in what other compilers do to this code, like Microsoft's and Intel's.  Clang does basically the same thing as gcc.)

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [`std::isnan()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) and [`std::isinf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isinf). You should not attempt to write these functions yourself given that they exist as part of the standard library.

Now, I have a nagging doubt that these functions are not present in the standard library that ships with VS2010. In which case you can work around the omission by using functions provided by the CRT. Specifically the following functions declared in `float.h`: `_isnan()`, `_finite(x)` and `_fpclass()`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am awre of those. The real issue is that they are available since C++11. Saddly Visual C++ 2010 hasn't got these C++11 features. In order to use those I'd need Visual C++ 2012, but I dont have the time & the net speed to download it.

Comment: @RavelT I think you would really benefit from using a more modern VS. It is worth the time. In any case, I added a workaround, because I anticipated your problem.

Comment: hm interesting, so I should use them like this: if (_finite(Fx)==1 || _isnan(Fx)==1)  Fx=0.0f; ? Seems not to work.

Comment: Don't test for return value of 1. Docs say that they return non-zero value to indicate true. Test `!= 0`. I think that `_fpclass()` may be more useful to you.

Comment: They typically don't return `1` because they usually work by simple bitops. I.e. a number is INF if the exponent is all ones and the significand is all zeroes. So, treat the float as int, you could mask of the sign, add one to the exponent (so the sign field overflows in the mask and remaining bits are 0), mask the sign again, and check if the result is 0. But this can produce pretty much any other results but 0 on failure.